# Спайп списков в ScrollView

Tags: react-native, animate, swipe

Некоторое время изучаю React Native и дошел до анимаций, свайпов и прочих штук с ними связанных.
Передвигать шарик конечно весело, но заинтересовался более сложными вещами, а именно, как работает функционал в некоторых маркетплейсах. Есть основной скролл, в нем шапка, категории и список товаров. Свайпами влево/вправо по списку товаров переключаются категории.
Интересует именно вот эти свайпы и независимые списки товаров.
Уже второй день ломаю над этим голову, но что-то ничего не придумывается. Пробовал искать готовый решения, но если честно, даже не знаю как правильно это все называется и как правильно составить запрос.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, есть ли статьи на эту тему (как создавать подобные компоненты), может есть готовые компоненты.

Спасибо за внимание!

ЗЫ: подобный функционал имеется в приложении додо пицца